# How can I change some specific carps into croaks in Perl?

Tags: perl, eval, warnings, carp

I tried to catch a carp-warning:

```
 carp "$start is > $end" if (warnings::enabled()); )
```

with [eval {}](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html) but it didn't work, so I looked in the `eval` documentation and I discovered, that `eval` catches only syntax-errors, run-time-errors or executed die-statements.

How could I catch a carp warning?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use 5.012;
use List::Util qw(max min);
use Number::Range;

my @array;
my $max = 20;
print "Input (max $max): ";
my $in = <>;

$in =~ s/\s+//g;
$in =~ s/(?<=\d)-/../g;

eval {
    my $range = new Number::Range( $in );
    @array = sort { $a <=> $b } $range->range;
};
if ( $@ =~ /\d+ is > \d+/ ) { die $@ }; # catch the carp-warning doesn't work 

die "Input greater than $max not allowed $!" if defined $max and max( @array ) > $max;
die "Input '0' or less not allowed $!" if min( @array ) < 1;
say "@array";
```

Comment: Is the question "How do I modify a warning message before it gets printed?" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your comments, my understanding is that you would like to make `carp` into a fatal warning.

If it is acceptable to make all `carp` warnings in your target package into fatal errors you can monkey-patch `carp`.

Carping Package:

```
package Foo;
use Carp;

sub annoying_sub {
    carp "Whine whine whine";
}
```

Main program:

```
use Foo;

*Foo::carp = \&Foo::croak;

Foo::annoying_sub();
```

If you want to limit the monkey patch to a dynamic scope, you can use `local`:

```
use Foo;

Foo::annoying_sub();  # non-fatal

{   local *Foo::carp = \&Foo::croak;
    Foo::annoying_sub();  # Fatal
}
```

Comment: These are some of the techniques I talk about in _Mastering Perl_ for changing code without editing the original source :)

Comment: It looks like the line "local *Foo::carp = \&Foo::croak;" should be "local *Foo::carp = \&Foo::croak();" to get a die instead ot the warning ("Warning...Subroutine Number::Range::carp redefined at...").

Answer (score 3):

carp does not die but just prints a warning, so there's nothing to catch with eval or whatever. You can, however, overwrite the warn handler locally to prevent the warning from being sent to stderr:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;

use Carp;

carp "Oh noes!";

{
    local $SIG{__WARN__} = sub {
        my ($warning) = @_;

        # Replace some warnings:
        if($warning =~ /replaceme/) {
            print STDERR "My new warning.\n";
        }
        else {
            print STDERR $warning;
        }

        # Or do nothing to silence the warning.
    };

    carp "Wh00t!";
    carp "replaceme";
}

carp "Arrgh!";
```

Output:

```
Oh noes! at foo.pl line 8
Wh00t! at foo.pl line 25
My new warning.
Arrgh! at foo.pl line 29
```

In almost all cases you should prefer fixing the cause of the carp instead.

Comment: My goal is not to silencing the carps but change a certain carp-warning in a die;

Comment: I updated the example to demonstrate how to replace the output.

Comment: Sorry, I think I got you wrong. Do you want to replace the warning text or do you want to die when a certain warning comes up?

Comment: to die when a certain warning comes up.

Comment: In that case, insert a die statement instead of the print the __WARN__ handler.